# Make HTML hidden input visible

Tags: javascript, html, visibility

I want to change an invisible HTML input in to visible when I click a button as shown below.

My HTML line that create the hidden input is:

```
<input type="hidden" id="txtHiddenUname" value="invalid input" />
```

my JavaScript for changing the visibility is:

```
var y = document.getElementById("txtHiddenUname");
y.style.display= "inline";
```

But this couldn't make the hidden element to be visible.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to change the value to "valid input", otherwise it's still invalid ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should change the type of input element as :

```
 y.setAttribute('type','text'); 
 //or
 y.type = 'text';
```

1) Either user java script inside body tag as below :

```
<input type="hidden" id="txtHiddenUname" value="invalid input" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var y = document.getElementById("txtHiddenUname");
y.type= "text";
</script>
```

**OR**

2) Use some event handler such as `onload`

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function on_load(){
    var y = document.getElementById("txtHiddenUname");
    y.type= "text";
}
    </script>
</head>

<body onload = "on_load()">

<input type="hidden" id="txtHiddenUname" value="invalid input" />

...
```

so that the DOM is ready.

Comment: I tried it and indeed it makes the text visible. but the visibility stays for milliseconds and it goes back to invisible mode.

Comment: use this code after some events occures on some element , like button click or someting else.

Answer (score 2):

Here is not matter of CSS it's matter of attributes, So you need to change the attribute `type` from `hidden` to something else like `text`

Kindly check this [how-to-change-html-object-element-data-attribute-value-in-javascript][1]

check this: [How to change HTML Object element data attribute value in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836290/how-to-change-html-object-element-data-attribute-value-in-javascript). To change the attribute value using jQuery or Javascript