# javascript from HTML How to make hidden image visible within function call?

Tags: javascript, image, hidden, visible

I'm having a problem with combined html and javascript where in one case I can make an image visible and in the other case I cannot.

I have one working example,"Switch on the Light" , where a hidden image **is** made visible
    This makes the picture of a lightbulb visible -

[image]
[image]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <center>
    <h1>Switch on the Light</h1>

    <img id="light" src="alternateCoolBulb.jpeg" style="width:100px" >
    <p>

      <input type="button" id="onButton" value="Turn On the Light" />
      <p>
    </center>

    </body>

    <script>

     function init() {
      document.getElementById("light").style.visibility = "hidden";
        var onButton = document.getElementById("onButton");
        onButton.onclick = function() {
         demoVisibility() ;
        }
      }

    function demoVisibility() {
        document.getElementById("light").style.visibility = "visible";
    }


     document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
          init();
        }
      });
    </script>
    </html>
```

Then I attempted to use this same idea of making the lightbulb visible in the example, "What is this Bird Called ". This example does not work right.
[image]

In this example, I put lightbulb images in table cells and set them to be hidden. The lightbulbs are images within a table cell, and that table cell is within a form.

I want to make the light bulb  visible when the user clicks on the correct answer using a radio button, and then clicks on the 'Check Answer' button associated with 'OnSubmitForm'.

In this example I have hardcoded the information to assume that the second answer is the correct answer.

When I click on the second answer in the following, the light bulb does not appear. I don't get any errors in the console log - but the lightbulb does not become visible.

I wonder if...

there is something different about using 
     
and resetting the visibility attribute - as done in the first working example

AND

changing an image attribute inside a table cell in a form

OR

There is something about using the on-click in the first working example that works differently

NOTE1 I **am** able to change the labels of the radio buttons within the table, that makes me think I should be able to change other things within the table

NOTE2 I created a third row test where there is no radio button in the same row as a light bulb image and I attempt to change the light bulb image from hidden to visible within my init function, instead of within the OnSubmitForm function. That does not work either. This is the cell that shows "Turn a light on here - Within Init Function...."

[image]

[image]

```
<html>
<center>
What is this bird called?
<p>
 <img id = "photo" src="img/testImages/spotted Sandpipler.JPG" 
    alt="a bird"

 height="150" width="100"style="clear: left" />
</center>
<table>
<form name="myform" onsubmit="OnSubmitForm();">

<tr>
<td>
   <input type="radio" id = 'first'  name="operation" value="1"
         > <label for="alsoFirst"> Answer 1 </label>
 </td>   



    <td>
```

**EDIT MADE HERE FROM SUGGESTION**

```
    <img style="visibility: hidden;" id="light1" src="img/alternateCoolBulb.jpeg" height="52" width="42"   >
    </td> 

</tr>

<tr>
<td>     
   <input type="radio" id = 'second'  name="operation" value="2">
  <label for="alsoSecond">Answer 2</label>
</td>
    <td>
```

**EDIT MADE HERE FROM SUGGESTION**

```
    <img style="visibility: hidden;" id="light2" src="img/alternateCoolBulb.jpeg" height="52" width="42"   >
    </td> 

</tr>

<tr>
<td>
Turn a light on here - Within init function - no use of the check answer button
</td>

  <td>
```

**EDIT MADE HERE FROM SUGGESTION**

```
    <img style="visibility: hidden;" id="light3" src="img/alternateCoolBulb.jpeg" height="52" width="42"   >
    </td> 

</tr>

   <p>

   </p>
</table>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check Answer">

</form>




<script type="text/javascript">
//history
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292962/javascript-how-to-change-radio-button-label-text
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954245/image-will-not-switch-between-hidden-and-show

 document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
  // Seems like a GOOD PRACTICE - keeps me from getting type error I was getting

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207922/javascript-error-null-is-not-an-object

    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
      init();
    }
  });

     function init() {

    console.log ("Init Function here ");
```

**BECAUSE OF EDITS above, made by folks here... All light bulbs NOW display when I put the following 3 lines in this init function**

```
    document.getElementById("light3").style.visibility = "visible";  
    document.getElementById("light2").style.visibility = "visible";  
    document.getElementById("light1").style.visibility = "visible";
```

[image]

**But when I comment the above 3 lines out, the OnSubmitForm does not manage to do same, no matter where I put the lines in the OnSubmitForm function, though it's obviously being invoked because of alert and console.log test**

```
    var label = document.getElementsByTagName('label') [0]; 
    label.innerHTML = 'Curlew ';

     var label1 = document.getElementsByTagName('label') [1]; 
    label1.innerHTML = 'Sandpiper';


    }

function OnSubmitForm()
{
// NONE of the light bulbs display when I put them anywhere in this function
  if(document.getElementById('first').checked == true)
    {
    //alert ( "You have selected the first answer - WRONG" );  
    console.log( "You have selected the first answer - WRONG" );  
    document.getElementById("light1").style.visibility = "visible";  

    }
  else
    if(document.getElementById('second').checked == true)
        {
        alert ( "You have selected the SECOND answer - RIGHT" );
        // This light bulb does not display - though the alert above is triggered
        document.getElementById("light2").style.visibility = "visible";  

        }
    // and for the heck of it I tried making all 3 lights visible here - no go
    document.getElementById("light1").style.visibility = "visible";  
    document.getElementById("light2").style.visibility = "visible";  
    document.getElementById("light3").style.visibility = "visible";  

  return false;
}

</script>




</html>
```

I tried to use ideas from [Make html hidden input visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638826/make-html-hidden-input-visible), but I could not figure out how to use the ideas in it. I tested the third line as below, but it did not hide it. So that may be the kind of thing to do, but I don't know how to incorporate it

```
<tr>
<td>
Turn a light on here - Within init function - no use of the check answer button
</td>

  <td>

    <img type="hidden" id="light3" src="img/alternateCoolBulb.jpeg" height="52" width="42"   >
    </td> 

</tr>
```

Comment: Have you heard of CSS ?

Comment: Please create jsfiddle and share link.

Comment: I don't have skills in CSS yet. So.... is there no way to do this without using CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you know this, but the type="hidden" is meant for the input tag and not the img tag. It defines the input type, and in this case it makes a hidden input for forms and not for styling. What you would want to do it,

```
<img style="visibility: hidden;" id="light3" src="img/alternateCoolBulb.jpeg" height="52" width="42"   >
```

Thus when your javascript runs, it actually changes the tags style visibility.

Comment: Oh you are right! I did not know that You were so polite - thank you. I will try this.

Comment: I can get this to work for light3 - that lightbulb picture is visible as soon as the init function is invoked, and is definitely hidden if I do not include that line within the init function. For some reason I'm not managing to get the OnSubmitForm function to get either the right or wrong answer light bulb picture to trigger, though the alerts are happening so I know my if/then are right. In this case, however, I wonder if there is something really basic I"m not seeing because I'm tired . I will look again when fresh. Am voting up now because it does work for that case. And thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Just you need to change the visibility in that input type.
        
                    
                    What is this bird called?

```
                 height="150" width="100"style="clear: left" />
                </center>
                <table>
                <form name="myform" onsubmit="OnSubmitForm();">

                <tr>
                <td>
                   <input type="radio" id = 'first'  name="operation" value="1"
                         > <label for="alsoFirst"> Answer 1 </label>
                 </td>   
                    <td>
                    <img id="light1" src="img/alternateCoolBulb.jpeg" height="52" width="42"  style="visibility: hidden;" >
                    </td> 
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>     
                   <input type="radio" id = 'second'  name="operation" value="2">
                  <label for="alsoSecond">Answer 2</label>
                </td>
                    <td>
                    <img id="light2" src="img/alternateCoolBulb.jpeg" height="52" width="42" style="visibility: hidden;" >
                    </td> 

                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>
                Turn a light on here - Within init function - no use of the check answer button
                </td>

                  <td>
                    <img style="visibility: hidden;" id="light3" src="img/alternateCoolBulb.jpeg" height="52" width="42"   >
                    </td> 

                </tr>

                   <p>

                   </p>
                </table>
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check Answer">

                </form>




                <script type="text/javascript">
                //history
                //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292962/javascript-how-to-change-radio-button-label-text
                //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954245/image-will-not-switch-between-hidden-and-show
                 document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
                  // Seems like a GOOD PRACTICE - keeps me from getting type error I was getting

                    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207922/javascript-error-null-is-not-an-object

                    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
                      init();
                    }
                  });

                 function init() {

                    console.log ("expect to change -Answer 1- displayed by first button  ");
                    // This light bulb does not display either...
                    document.getElementById("light3").style.visibility = "visible";  
                    var label = document.getElementsByTagName('label') [0]; 
                    label.innerHTML = 'Curlew ';

                     var label1 = document.getElementsByTagName('label') [1]; 
                    label1.innerHTML = 'Sandpiper';


                    }

                function OnSubmitForm()
                {
                  if(document.getElementById('first').checked == true)
                    {
                    alert ( "You have selected the first answer - WRONG" );  
                    }
                  else
                    if(document.getElementById('second').checked == true)
                        {
                        alert ( "You have selected the SECOND answer - RIGHT" );
                        // This light bulb does not display - though the alert above is triggered
                        document.getElementById("light2").style.visibility = "visible";  
                        return true;
                        }
                  return false;
                }


                </script>
```

Comment: Boy this is driving me crazy! I am now getting any of the 3 lights to change when I put the change into the init function - but in the OnSubmit they do not change - though it's clear I'm in the function as I can get alert and console.log's to trigger. And no errors in the console log to give me a clue... I will add the code to above problem writeup.

Comment: I edited in code changes, based on Tishbyte (and Iqbal's) suggestions. I can see improved behavior in the code, though I'm still having a problem. I'm not sure if my (edited) code makes sense anymore, because now I still have a problem, but the problem has changed somewhat. So I don't know if my edited code makes sense.

Comment: The code works fine if I only want to make one or more fields visible in my init function, but if I attempt to change any images from hidden to visible in  any place in my OnSubmitForm function, the images remain hidden - though that function is definitely being invoked.

Comment: I have restarted this as a new problem, because my original question was resolved and the edits I added here are confusing. They reflect a different problem.   I have made an even simpler version of my example in the new posting as well.  The new version is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756163/javascript-from-html-how-to-make-image-visible-from-submit-function-no-css