# Change data-attribute on click of HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute, htmlcollection

I am trying to apply changes to the DOM when a `<tr>` is clicked. When clicked, it should add `data-state=enabled` and `data-display=expanded` to the clicked `<tr>` while applying `data-state=disabled` and `data-display=collapsed` to **every other** `<tr>`.

So it should look like highlighting the clicked row while disabling the other rows.

Then, when a row is highlighted, and a user clicks elsewhere, it should **reset to default**, i.e. `data-state=enabled` and `data-display=collapsed` for all `<tr>`'s

Currently, I have it working so that when a `<tr>` is clicked, that row is highlighted and all others disabled. However, **the script is missing the reset to default** because if another `<tr>` is clicked, it immediately highlights that one and disables the rest.

I would like to do this in vanilla javascript but I am also open to using jQuery if it is substantially easier and won't affect performance noticably.

Here is the JSbin with working code to see where it's at:
https://jsbin.com/kirati/

And the code so far:

```
<table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="sort-key asc"><a href="#">Pet Name </a></th>
                            <th><a href="#">Owner (Last, First)</a></th>
                            <th><a href="#">Species</a></th>
                            <th><a href="#">Breed</a></th>
                            <th><a href="#">ID</a></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Fluffy
                                <div class="table-row__expanded-content">
                                    <data-key>Sex: </data-key> <data-value>Male</data-value><br />
                                    <data-key>DOB: </data-key> <data-value>12/08/2010</data-value> <br />
                                    <data-key>Weight: </data-key> <data-value>20 lbs</data-value> <br />
                                    <data-key>Location: </data-key> <data-value>Kennel 2B</data-value> <br />
                                    <data-key>Temperament: </data-key> <data-value>Aggresive</data-value> <br />
                                    <data-key>Allergies: </data-key> <data-value>Sulfa, Penicillin, Peanuts</data-value>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>Anderson, James</td>
                            <td>Dog</td>
                            <td>Bulldog-Shitzu</td>
                            <td>ABCDE1234567</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Feather</td>
                            <td>Michelle Charlotte, <br /> Angel Vanessa</td>
                            <td>Cat</td>
                            <td>American Bobtail</td>
                            <td>FGHIJ1234567</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Fluffer-Nutter</td>
                            <td>Rakerstraw, Rickey</td>
                            <td>Dog</td>
                            <td>American Eskimo</td>
                            <td>KLMNO1234567</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Farley</td>
                            <td>Cunningham, Stephanie</td>
                            <td>Dog</td>
                            <td>Pomeranian</td>
                            <td>PQRST1234567</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Fuzzy</td>
                            <td>Venice, Harding</td>
                            <td>Cat</td>
                            <td>Burmese</td>
                            <td>UVWXY1234567</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="alphabet-label">

                            <td>G</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Goldie</td>
                            <td>Cherilyn, Mitchener</td>
                            <td>Dog</td>
                            <td>Chihuahua-Maltese</td>
                            <td>ZABCD1234567</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

And the Javascript

```
window.onload = function () {

    var tablerow = document.body.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    console.log(tablerow);

     // Convert the HTMLCollection into a true javascript Array, so we can do "stuff" with it       
    var tablerowArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tablerow);
    console.log(tablerowArr);

// Do stuff
    tablerowArr.forEach(function (value, i) {
        console.log(i, value);

        tablerow[i].onclick = function (e) {
            //console.log("clicked!");


            var newArr = tablerowArr.slice(i, i + 1);
            //console.log(tablerow);
            console.log(i);
            //console.log(tablerowArr);
            console.log('newArr', newArr);


            tablerowArr.forEach(function (value, i) {

                // first reset all instances of data-XXX  
                tablerowArr[i].setAttribute('data-display', "collapsed");
               // tablerowArr[i].setAttribute('data-state', "enabled");

                // Set the <tr> data-display attribute to expanded/collapsed on click
                newArr[0].setAttribute('data-display', tablerowArr[i].getAttribute('data-display') === "collapsed" ? "expanded" : "collapsed");
                //tablerowArr[i].setAttribute('data-display', tablerowArr[i].getAttribute('data-display') === "collapsed" ? "expanded" : "collapsed");

                // Set the <tr> data-state attribute to enabled/disabled on click
                newArr[0].setAttribute('data-state', newArr[0].getAttribute('data-state') === "disabled" ? "enabled" : "enabled");
                tablerowArr[i].setAttribute('data-state', newArr[0].getAttribute('data-state') === "enabled" ? "disabled" : "enabled");

            });

            e.preventDefault();
        };
    });
};
```

Comment: try this solution maybe it may help
[How to change HTML Object element data attribute value in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836290/how-to-change-html-object-element-data-attribute-value-in-javascript) or this one [Set data attribute using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286661/set-data-attribute-using-javascript)

Comment: "use jQuery if it is substantially easier and won't affect performance noticably" - it always is substantially easier and it doesn't affect performance

Comment: I prefer VanillaJS because it helps me better understand JavaScript rather than relying on "magic" from cool libraries like jQuery. Of course there is a time and place for libraries because they make some stuff super easy - but there are times when pureJS is just fine (and helps my understanding grow).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set data attribute using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286661/set-data-attribute-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure javascript example in the below jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pya9jzxm/14

```
    var tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
    var trs = tbody.querySelectorAll('tr');
    var tr, index = 0, length = trs.length;
    for (; index < length; index++) {
        tr = trs[index];
        tr.setAttribute('data-state', 'enabled');
        tr.setAttribute('data-display', 'collapsed');
        tr.addEventListener('click',
            function () {
                if (this.classList.contains('alphabet-label')) {
                    return;
                }
                var trIndex = 0, trLength = trs.length, hasExpanded = false;
                var state = 'disabled';
                if (tbody.querySelectorAll('[data-display="expanded"]').length > 0) {
                    hasExpanded = true;
                    state = 'enabled';
                }
                for (; trIndex < trLength; trIndex++) {
                    trs[trIndex].setAttribute('data-state', state);
                    trs[trIndex].setAttribute('data-display', 'collapsed');
                }
                if (!hasExpanded) {
                    this.setAttribute('data-state', 'enabled');
                    this.setAttribute('data-display', 'expanded');
                }
            }
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I see that it works to highlight on click, however the part I was missing was getting it to reset to default after clicking off of a row which is highlighted.  i.e. first click away from highlighted row makes every row is unhighlighted, second click then highlights the new row.

Comment: OK, so even clicking another row deselects everything first? Or just clicking away from any row in an area that is not a row?

Comment: Updated fiddle where clicking other rows removes highlight first. and then click again adds it to new row.

Comment: Thanks! You did it perfectly!! Pure JS too - even better :-)

Comment: One more thing - how to get it to not highlight the <thead> data like pawel did. Meaning it should only highlight actually data <tr>'s but not the first <tr> inside the <thead>

Comment: Removed some duplicated code if you are interested. Answer updated.

Comment: Updated to answer to ignore header row as well.

Comment: Amazing. Last update: instead of all starting at "disabled", I'd like all rows to start "enabled". I tried adjusting line 5 to `tr.setAttribute('data-state', 'enabled');` however now it starts enabled, then first click disables all (undesired), then it starts the procedure like normal. So it should all be enabled at start and then go right into the highlighting.

Comment: My mistake, I should clarify: `data-state=enabled` and `data-display=collapsed` is the default **and** the reset for all. On highlight, `data-display=expanded` and `data-state` remains enabled (for the clicked row) and all others `data-display=collapsed` and `data-state=disabled`. Then on click away, apply the reset which puts `data-stated=enabled` and `data-display=collapsed` for all (including previously highlighed row)

Comment: That's the one!! Version 7. Thank you once again for the excellent support. I'm working on a big project for a company.

Comment: Haha. Cool. No problem! Happy to help! Good luck on the project!

Comment: Just for fun here is a little cleaner version 8 removing duplicated code. http://jsfiddle.net/pya9jzxm/8/

Comment: Neat! I like the cleanliness of it. As they say, keep your code DRY.

Comment: Lol you're on a roll!

Comment: OK, I am stopping after this but that display variable is useless. I removed it.

Comment: Hey I figured another update out - I combined part of version 4 with version 11 and made this: I needed to skip the row where it says "G" because that's just a label row and not actual row data, so it should not be highlightable. http://jsfiddle.net/pya9jzxm/13/

Comment: All is perfect now. Thanks again - Cheers!

Comment: One more update to your edit. For sake of possibly using multiple classes I suggest using classList.contains

Comment: Hey AtheistP3ace, would you take a look at my other question? It's about how to convert this code we did here to support multiple tables on a page instead of just one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516684/convert-script-to-handle-multiple-tables-independently

Comment: Yea I can take a look. Give me a little. At work right now.

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('html').click(function() {
        /* return to default state */
        $('.table tbody tr').data('state', 'enabled').data('display', 'expanded');
    });
    $('.table tbody tr').on('click', function(e) {
        /* stop the html click event */
        e.stopPropagation();
        /* set attributes for all rows */
        $('.table tbody tr').data('state', 'disabled').data('display', 'collapsed');
        /* set attributes for the clicked row */
        $(this).data('state', 'enabled').data('display', 'expanded');
    });
});
```

I've commented the function, to clarify how it works.

Comment: just double check $(this).data( do you not mean $(this).attr( ?

Comment: When I added this to my JSbin with jquery loaded, the script did not work, using (this).data and (this).attr - see JS bin with original code: https://jsbin.com/xukiyoragu

Comment: @freedomn-m do you mind posting a link to support your claim as I have one which directly contradict you https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: @TetraDev see my answer for jquery. also may i  suggest you change some of this to work off html classes instead of data attributes, unless there is some other framework which you are relying on.

Comment: @freedomn-m the one modifies the DOM the other does not.... so ask yourself the same question. He wants to modify **the DOM** not underlining model data... so ... I hope that helps you understand the diff **between attr and data**. **He wants to modify the actual HTML in the page.**

Comment: @freedomn-m i thought it was quite clear! May I suggest that you change your other comment **attr("state") isn't the same as attr("data-state")** as i have no idea what you are trying to say. Now that you know the diff between data and attr maybe you can word that a little clearer. thx

Comment: no offence, but you could read you own comment, to see that you did not. there is no shame in that!, FYI you made me google data, and triple!!! check it. It wasn't clear to you, you should not include everyone in that... and no one said that last line!

Comment: Lol you guys are funny. But thanks because I learned something about .data and .attr - although I'm curious what the use case would be for changing DOM data using .data?

Comment: @Seabizkit Not sure why I'm referenced in all those comments - exactly what are you referring to?

Comment: **deletes all his comments** but the last one, weird...anyway @TetraDev JQuery .data does not modify the DOM... its keep meta information in javascript about a given JQuery element... but best read up on it, I had to as i wasn't sure hence the original comment (double check..)... as i wasn't sure, after checking due to someone else's comment saying it was incorrect, i had to check for myself what data does.

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla JS and event delegation.  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08zunp2/2/)

```
var tablerow = document.body.getElementsByTagName('tr');
// Convert the HTMLCollection into a true javascript Array, so we can do "stuff" with it       
var tablerowArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tablerow);
// store the highlighted row
var highlighted;

// extracted function to enable/disable rows
var enable = function(row){
    row.setAttribute('data-display', "expanded");
    row.setAttribute('data-state', "enabled");
}
var disable = function( row ){
    row.setAttribute('data-display', "collapsed");
    row.setAttribute('data-state', "disabled");
}
// on click anywhere
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var target = e.target;
    // check if event target or any of its parents is a TR
    while( target.parentNode && target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'tr' ){
        target = target.parentNode;   
    }
    // if s row was higlighted disable all rows
    if( highlighted ){
        tablerowArr.forEach(  disable );
        // and remove the reference to highlighted
        highlighted = null;
    }
    // no row is highlighted
    else {
        tablerowArr.forEach( function(row){
            // if the event target is a row, highlight it
            if(row == target) {
                enable( row );
                // and store it as the currently highlighted
                highlighted = row;
            }
            // if it's not the event target then disable
            else {
                disable( row ); 
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Works great except it is also missing the "reset to default" after clicking off of a row which is highlighted. i.e. first click away from highlighted row makes every row is unhighlighted, second click then highlights the new row.

Comment: @TetraDev I have focused on the "clicking anywhere" part to remove highlights. Fixed now to remove highlight on first click.

Comment: Thanks - that part works. But I did not communicate clearly - on the reset, all rows should go back to default `data-state-enabled` and `data-display=collapsed`. Right now, when the "reset" is applied, all rows are disabled and collapsed (should be enabled and collapsed)

Answer (score 0):

Which is very simular to @LinkinTED

Please inspect the html before you say this does not work.. I've tested it myself.

May i suggest that you instead modify the class... to change the effects.

```
$(function() {

    var $row = $('.table tbody tr');

    $('html').click(function() {
        $row.attr('state', 'enabled').attr('display', 'expanded');
    });

    $row.on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $row
          .attr('state', 'disabled')
          .attr('display', 'collapsed');

      //console.log(e);

        $(this)
          .attr('state', 'enabled')
          .attr('display', 'expanded');
    });
});
```

Comment: It works if I edit the attr to data-state and data-display (that's what my css required). Although it is only missing the "reset" when clicking to another row after being highlighted. It resets if I click anywhere in the DOM which is not a <tr> but it should also reset even when clicking another <tr> before applying the next highlight.

Comment: OK but is this just to: highlight row, and show hidden data when clicked, if so I would change this to add and remove classes instead of working off attributes. You could just add a check in to meet your additional requirement. Also if you don't like the rest variable you could change it.

Comment: It's not a matter of 'inspecting the html' because OP is using *css* which is looking for attributes "data-state" so `attr("state")` isn't the same as `attr("data-state")`

Comment: I wanted to avoid using classes to change states because I want to keep my classes clean and minimal, and use html5 data- properties for best practice. Just my personal preference.

Comment: @TetraDev ... just so you are aware... maybe im wrong but i dont think so... the more correct way.... even with html5 and attr's, to do this, is with classes.... if you think im wrong... you could ask this on SO. (but remember i called it ;-)), you could using common classes like "hide" part of bootstrap, and you already using css... so... not sure why you think classes is not the correct way to modify the dom. attr are usually used to carry info, not to affect styling...just an FYI, hope this was useful.

Comment: Just to add: classes are for changing the appearance on the page.  You're changing the appearance by "highlighting", so should be a class.

Comment: You may be correct.  Although I don't prefer the bootstrap method of littering my html with classes. I abstract all classes away into the CSS and use SASS as a preprocessor to manipulate my display. See this for my reasoning behind data-xxx: http://toddmotto.com/stop-toggling-classes-with-js-use-behaviour-driven-dom-manipulation-with-data-states/

Comment: I consider it to be more of a state change than a highlighting. The highlighting is only the effect of the state change - the state is the primary focus.